# Infinite flashlight

Tags: fear

Flashlight needs to be recharged (by turning it off) and energy runs out quickly. Without light *nothing* can be seen in the dark and managing battery quickly becomes an annoyance. How can I disable discharging?
I assume that this is possible as there's a [mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/fear-mmod/news/fear-mmod) (with a lot of other major changes) which increases the recharge rate.

Comment: For the record, I think [tag:fear] is the right tag.

Comment: @TimmyJim: "F.E.A.R." is the game's official title. I've asked to merge the existing tag.